# Connect VM present in KVM to Mininet switch

Tags: python, virtual-machine, mininet

So, I'm working on a project that requires Linux host running different programs, and a BMv2 P4 switch in Mininet.

I thought a topology as running VM in KMV with my applications running on them and connecting it to BMv2 switch in the Mininet. Is it possible to do so?? And if you, can you guide me how can I connect KVM Linux as Host to Mininet, and send traffic through the switch. Any kind of help will be great.

Thanks and Regards

I want to connect Linux host running different programs and a BMv2 P4 switch in Mininet.